# Update table from database using ajax in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I have a problem. I want update my table data from database with selected value's for select box (dropdown). And i think ajax is solution. But how can i do it?
 Here is my select tag in **VIEW**. My view is writtin in haml

```
%select{:name => "options", :id=>"select_other_month"}
            %option{:value => "0"} Other Months
            %option{:value => "5"} 5
            %option{:value => "4"} 4
            %option{:value => "3"} 3
            %option{:value => "2"} 2
            %option{:value => "1"} 1
```

and here is my table

```
.table{:id=>"admin_time_table"}
        %table{:border=>"1"}
            %tr
                %th No
                %th Name
                %th Total day 
                %th Total time
            -@i = 1
            -@users.each do |u|
                %tr
                    %td=@i
                    %td=u.firstname
                    %td=u.total_day
                    %td=u.total_time
                -@i = @i +1
```

and my controller looks like

```
@users = User.where(:type_id=>0)
```

I mean when i select 4 in dropdown, table data reloaded with April data from database.

**Note:** My database is mysql.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you asking for a tutorial on how to use Ajax with Rails, or where best to insert it in this code?

Comment: I am asking how to use Ajax with Rails

Comment: Then your question is far too broad--start by reading the [Rails guide to JS](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) Put your select into the form with `remote: true` option. That will make it submit though ajax. Can also set up a javascript listener to submit it every time it changes. You should see it hitting rails server at this point and getting routing error

2) Set up the route for this action.

3) In a controller action read the `select_other_month` value from `params`

4) In a view `action.js.erb` (has to be `js`). do 
`$("#admin_time_table").html("<%= j render partial: 'table' %>")`. Where the table partial is the replacement with data for the specified `type_id`

You'll need to play and tweak it to make it work with your system. But you get the idea